# Bugzilla 5.0 with mod_perl on CentOS 6.3 - "Internal Server Error" on some pages

Tags: apache, centos6, bugzilla, mod-perl2

I have a Bugzilla 5.0 installation running on CentOS. It was running really slow with CGI, so I configured it to use mod_perl. Most of the pages work and the speed has improved too. On some of the admin pages I get:

---

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

---

Within the server error log, there are errors like:

---

[error] Attempt to reload Carp/Heavy.pm aborted.\nCompilation failed in require at /usr/local/lib64/perl5/APR/Error.pm line 29.\nCompilation failed in require at (eval 510) line 1.\n

---

I tried reinstalling APR and mod_perl but that didn't fix the issue. Googling also didn't lead much on this issue.

Will appreciate some pointers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a conflict between /usr/share/perl5/Carp/Heavy.pm and /var/www/html/bugzilla/lib/Carp/Heavy.pm. the former one is supplied by Centos, and the latter one is downloaded by bugzilla's script(install-module.pl).

Since I don't know much about Perl, So the simplest(maybe not the right one) workaround I found is to execute the following command:

```
mv /var/www/html/bugzilla/lib/Carp/Heavy.pm /var/www/html/bugzilla/lib/Carp/Heavy.pm.bak
cp /usr/share/perl5/Carp/Heavy.pm /var/www/html/bugzilla/lib/Carp
```

P.S.: "/var/www/html/bugzilla/" is my bugzilla installation dir, change it accordingly when you issue the command.